# Replaces characters under condition

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm looking for a regular expression to replace a group of spaces by the same number of dots on space groups which fulfill a certain condition.

Test case: replace spaces ending non "empty" lines with dots

```
TODO LIST:          |
==========          |
- item1             |
    * subitem1.1    |
    * subitem1.2    |
                    |
- item2             |
    * subitem2.1    |
    * subitem2.2    |
                    |
Some text... blah!  |
```

Should be transformed to (please note the space between items and `...`):

```
TODO LIST:          |
==========          |
- item1 ............|
    * subitem1.1 ...|
    * subitem1.2 ...|
                    |
- item2 ............|
    * subitem2.1 ...|
    * subitem2.2 ...|
                    |
Some text... blah!  |
```

I've got the feeling I should use pre- and post-conditions, but I have no idea how. I use `sed` but `perl` would be ok.

Comment: so only lines starting with `-` or `*` should be considered?

Comment: Are the pipe characters `|` really in the file?

Comment: @Sundeep that's right!

Comment: @Borodin yes they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*[^ ] (*SKIP)(*F)| /./g if /^\h*[*-]/' ip.txt 
TODO LIST:          |
==========          |
- item1 ............|
    * subitem1.1 ...|
    * subitem1.2 ...|
                    |
- item2 ............|
    * subitem2.1 ...|
    * subitem2.2 ...|
                    |
Some text... blah!  |
```

- `if /^\h*[*-]/` only lines of interest
- `^.*[^ ] (*SKIP)(*F)` this pattern (from start of line to last non-space character followed by space character) won't be changed

  - Further reading: http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail and http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html
- `|`  alternate pattern, these will be replaced with `.`
- use `perl -i -pe` for in-place editing

Comment: This is unnecessarily arcane. There are few people who understand how this works, and even they would take several seconds to comprehend its purpose. You're welcome to explore the corners of a language, and if you want to become a professional then it's essential, but there's no reason to inflict your joy of new discoveries on others who are trying to write maintainable code. I'm pretty certain that the OP @YSC doesn't understand it and couldn't fix it if they wanted to, let alone their colleagues who will probably be stumped. This would need copious comments in context to explain its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

This will do as you ask. There's no need to cram everything into a single regex, so I first check to see if the line starts with possible spaces followed by a dash `-` or a star `*`, and then convert all trailing spaces apart from the first into the same number of dots `.` using an *expression* replacement

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    s/\S[ ]\K([ ]+)/ '.' x length $1 /e if /^\s*[-*]/;

    print;
}

__DATA__
TODO LIST:          |
==========          |
- item1             |
    * subitem1.1    |
    * subitem1.2    |
                    |
- item2             |
    * subitem2.1    |
    * subitem2.2    |
                    |
Some text... blah!  |
```

#### output

```
TODO LIST:          |
==========          |
- item1 ............|
    * subitem1.1 ...|
    * subitem1.2 ...|
                    |
- item2 ............|
    * subitem2.1 ...|
    * subitem2.2 ...|
                    |
Some text... blah!  |
```

Comment: A line with two spaces, like «  * two  spaces  fail      |»  fails. This may not be a problem if the input is known not to have two spaces ever. A more complicate regex will match what the OP stated as the criteria: `s{ [-*] .*?  \s \K (\s+) \| }{ q{.} x length($1) . q{|} }emsx;`

Comment: @shawnhcorey: I'm not clear what you mean. Your example has only one space between `fail` and the pipe, which is left as a space. If there were two spaces there then the second one would be changed to a dot.

Comment: There are two spaces between "two" and "spaces" and between "spaces" and "fail".

Comment: @shawnhcorey: Ah okay. They're not in the comment, which contains `like \xAB * two spaces fail |\xBB fails`. You should use backticks to delineate space-sensitive text in comments. I left my code that way deliberately, as it was a choice between allowing for multiple spaces before the end of the text and writing something much less intelligible.

Comment: wouldn't `/^.*\S[ ]\K([ ]+)/` cover the case of multiple spaces too?

Comment: @Borodin I tried backticks; they didn't work. The formatter didn't pick up the first one.

Comment: @Sundeep Yes but it has a lot of backtracking.